# converting all possible string dates to date objects

Tags: java, string, date

I need to be able to convert all possible string representations of a date to a Date object. I know that this is not a trivial task and I mainly ask for guidance, as I believe there is no 'one-liner' solution.

Current example for just one possible input class: `return new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(input);`

To clarify my question, here are some possible string inputs:

- 30-08-2011
- 25.06.2011
- 15 Juni 2011
- 01-07-11
- 19-9-2011

The data is handed over by a third party, so I cannot do anything about that. I had some thoughts about checking what the delimeter is and choosing the correct format based on that.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards.

**EDIT:** I have access to the Locale of the user, in this way I can actually distinguish between the day and the month parts. Or rather put differently, I have access to the locale of the date.

Comment: You are somewhat stuck in a non-deterministic solution.  For example is 05-06-2011 May 6 2011, or June 5, 2011.  Sorry dude.

Comment: I have access to the locale of the user, I'll update the OP with this.

Comment: You can try one after the other until you get a date (and hope it is correct as @Pete pointed out) or define a clear interface to the third party. There is also the question why there are sent different date formats.

Comment: Not desirable but still solution: put all possible formats in string array, and try to parse date string until you succeed or run-out data-formats (in this case rethrow exception).

Comment: @UwePlonus They are invoices that have went through an OCR. And wouldn't trying multiple formats cause overhead in the form of ParseExceptions?

Comment: I would suggest that you request a detailed specification of the data feed from the third party. They should be able to, at the very least, constrain and specify the list of possible date formats that they supply to you.

Comment: The OCR info frames the question better and should be part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uglier code than I thought. So I'll give it.
Splitting tokens, filling the 3 date components.
One would still need to find the order of those components for the given locale: Mdy, dMy.

```
public class DateIn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] dates = {
            "30-08-2011",
            "25.06.2011",
            "15 Juni 2011",
            "01-07-11",
            "19-9-2011",
        };
        DateIn in = new DateIn();
        Locale locale = Locale.US;
        for (String date : dates) {
            try {
                Date d = in.read(date, locale);
                System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", date,
                    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(d));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private Date read(String date, Locale locale)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        final String[] ymdFormatters = { "y", "M", "d" };
        final int[] ymdGetters = { Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH,
            Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH };
        String[] tokens = date.split("\\W+");
        final int Y = 0;
        final int M = 1;
        final int D = 2;
        int[] ymdValues = new int[3];
        for (String token : tokens) {
            if (token.matches("\\d+\\pL+")) { // 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 1e, ...
                token = token.replaceAll("\\pL+", "");
                ymdValues[D] = Integer.parseInt(token);
            } else if (token.matches("\\d+")) {
                int n = Integer.parseInt(token);
                if (n > 31) {
                    ymdValues[Y] = n;
                } else if (n > 12) {
                    ymdValues[D] = n;
                } else {
                    // Locale dependent order.
                    if (ymdValues[M] == 0) {
                        ymdValues[M] = n;
                    } else if (ymdValues[D] == 0) {
                        ymdValues[D] = n;
                    } else if (ymdValues[Y] == 0) {
                        ymdValues[Y] = n;
                    }
                }
            } else if (!token.isEmpty()) {
                for (int md = M; md <= D; ++md) {
                    String fmt = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                        fmt += ymdFormatters[md];
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(fmt);
                        sdf.setLenient(true);
                        try {
                            Date dt = sdf.parse(token);
                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
                            cal.setTime(dt);
                            int n = cal.get(ymdGetters[md]);
                            if (md == M) {
                                ++n; // To 1-based
                            }
                            ymdValues[md] = n;
                            break;
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            //continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
        for (int md = Y; md <= D; ++md) {
            int n = ymdValues[md];
            if (n == 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing "
                    + ymdFormatters[md] + " part in " + date);
            }
            if (md == Y) {
                if (n < 100)
                    n += (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) / 100) * 100;
            } else if (md == M) {
                --n; // Calendar's month is 0-based.
            }
            calendar.set(ymdGetters[md], n);
        }
        return calendar.getTime();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A first idea could be to detect the non-numerical and nonalphabetic characters. These characters seperate months, days and years in a date. In your examples these are '-', ' ' and '.'.

Next you split the string according to the detected seperator character.

This gives you: ["30","08","2011] in the first case.

Then we can check if the year is first or last. This can be done by checking the number of digits. If numDigits==4 then you know which one is the year. Otherwise you can check the range, is it's not in [1,31] then again it is a year. If they are both in [1,31] then I see no clear way of deciding. (perhaps you know more about the possibilities for year?)

Finally there's the middle string. There you simply check whether it contains alphabetical chars or numbers.

Comment: I think it is possible to infer day/month cq month/day from the locale. So this solution seems to be a good one.

Comment: What about 01-01-13 as date though?

Comment: It is simply ambiguous. If you have more information on your data you could make a dedicated guess though. As an example if the value > 13 it will likely be the day. If the dates you 're working with are in a certain time span say [2010,2013] that could also give you a clue, but 12-01-13 would still be almost impossible to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You could try splitting a string into its component parts(days, months, years) and parsing those individually.

ex:

```
String input = 30-08-2011;
if (input.indexOf("-") == -1)
return;
else    
   String day = index.substring(0, selected.indexOf("-"));
```

then the day, can be parsed individually. Then repeat the process for month and year. Then you don't have to worry about the formatting between the components of the date.